# Monzo API: Invalid request: required parameter client_id is unknown

Tags: api

I keep getting the following error `Invalid request: required parameter client_id is unknown` when making a request to the [monzo auth api](https://monzo.com/docs/#acquire-an-access-token) to get an access token. I am getting the client_id from the [developer playground](https://developers.monzo.com/api/playground) response using GET `/ping/whoami`.

I am then putting this into my request:

```
    let clientID = "oauthclient_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    let baseURL = "https://auth.monzo.com/"
    let redirectURI = "https://Monzo-AR.novoda.com"
    let responseType = "code"
    let stateToken = "random string"
    var requestURL: String!

    requestURL = baseURL +
                "?client_id=" +
                clientID +
                "&redirect_uri=" +
                redirectURI +
                "&response_type=" +
                responseType +
                "&state=" +
                stateToken
```

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/ping/whoami` endpoint returns the client_id for the Developer Console (which was used to authenticate you for that service)

It's not suggested to use that client_id in your own applications. If you head to the [Monzo Clients Page](https://developers.monzo.com/apps/home) you will be able to create your own client and receive an ID for it.

Additionally, the redirect URI must match that of the one configured in the clients page linked before (You will get an error otherwise)

You haven't given context to what you're doing with the `requestURL` - You will need to redirect the user to this page in order to authenticate.

Once you have been redirected to the authentication page at the link you've constructed, you'll be able to use your browsers console (`Cmd + Option + J` on Chrome Mac) to see any errors that present themselves